# How to create custom search with sub site1 and its sub sites in SP2013?

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, search-scope

we need a create a custom search having the requirement like to create a custom search at  subsite1 and its subsites only,i dont want to include sitecollection1  search results in subsite1.

can any one  give the query example how to exclude the sitecollection1 results in subsite1 
example/Sitecollecion1
example/Sitecollecion1/subsite1
example/Sitecollecion1/subsite1/subsite2
example/Sitecollecion1/subsite1/subsite3/subsite4

Answer (score 1):

Create result sources to limit the search results to the subsites only with the query like this: `{searchTerms} path:http://sitecollection1/subsite1`

Check this article:
http://techmikael.blogspot.in/2013/04/limiting-search-results-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: Please do not use images for code snippets, you can use markdown to make code-snippets of text